# How do I hide multiple pictureboxes at once?

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

My code:

```
Case 1 To 9
            txtPlanet.Text = "Mercury"
            pl1.Show()
            pl2.Hide()
            pl3.Hide()
            pl4.Hide()
            pl5.Hide()
            pl6.Hide()
            pl7.Hide()
            pl8.Hide()
            pl9.Hide()
```

How do I make it so it does it like this: pl1.Show, pl2-9.Hide.
If that isn't possible, what's the best solution to neaten the code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd do. It assumes you're using VB.NET in Visual Studio 2010.

```
Dim pictureBoxes = {pl1, pl2, pl3, ....}
Dim shownPicture = Nothing

Select Case planetToShow
    Case "Mercury"
        shownPicture = pl1
    Case "Venus"
        shownPicture = pl2

    ....

End Select

For Each pic in pictureBoxes.Except({shownPicture})
    pic.Hide()
Next

shownPicture.Show()
```

Answer (score 0):

a select case is not well written, becuase you only wrote the case, there has to be a if function statement.

```
Select case textPlanet.Text
  case "Mercury"
    pl1.Show()
    pl2.Hide()
    pl3.Hide()
    pl4.Hide()
    pl5.Hide()
    pl6.Hide()
    pl7.Hide()
    pl8.Hide()
    pl9.Hide()
  case "Venus"
    // Repeat above statements with pl2.Show() & pl1.Hide
 //Repeat each case for each planet        
  end case
```

i am not sure strings work correctly with cases, if not try with integer

Comment: In VB.NET, strings work correctly with cases. They are evaluated like multiple `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for Controls with .Controls.Find()
This returs an Array of the found Controls.
Then go through the Controls with for each...

You have to search for controls from the parent control. I.E. Form, Groupbox ...